# Error comparing the output of datepart to an integer

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that i have been tinkering with to use as a source for a report.
For some odd reason when i try to compare the output of datepart(dw,GetDate()) to an integer (2 for Monday) it gives me an error telling me incorrect syntax. i then started looking into why i couldn't compare two integers in an iif statement and... i have found absolutely no answers. 
here is the full code (i went back and forth on how to do this, this is this iterations attempt)

```
    DECLARE @dp integer,@d integer
    set @dp =DATEpart(dw,GETDATE())
    set @d = 2
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT CUST_ORDER_LINE.PRODUCT_CODE
        ,CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID
        ,CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID
        ,CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID
        ,CUST_ORDER_LINE.MISC_REFERENCE
        ,CUST_ORDER_LINE.COMMODITY_CODE
        ,CUSTOMER_ORDER.SALESREP_ID
        ,CUSTOMER_ORDER.TERRITORY
        ,CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY * CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE AS Amount
        ,CUSTOMER_ORDER.ORDER_DATE
    FROM CUST_ORDER_LINE
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_ORDER ON CUST_ORDER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID = CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID
    WHERE (
            iif(@dp = @d,CUSTOMER_ORDER.ORDER_DATE BETWEEN ( dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) - 3)  AND ( dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()),0))),
            CUSTOMER_ORDER.ORDER_DATE BETWEEN ( dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) - 1))  AND ( dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), + 1))))
            )
    ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ORDER.ORDER_DATE DESC
```

The point of this query is to pull data from yesterday, and Friday if it is Monday.

EDIT: error code Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Line 19: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: `iif` not in 2008. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IIF` is in 2012. You can try using `CASE` instead.

```
DECLARE @dp integer,@d integer
    set @dp =DATEpart(dw,GETDATE())
    set @d = 2
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT CUST_ORDER_LINE.PRODUCT_CODE
        ,CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID
        ,CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID
        ,CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID
        ,CUST_ORDER_LINE.MISC_REFERENCE
        ,CUST_ORDER_LINE.COMMODITY_CODE
        ,CUSTOMER_ORDER.SALESREP_ID
        ,CUSTOMER_ORDER.TERRITORY
        ,CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY * CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE AS Amount
        ,CUSTOMER_ORDER.ORDER_DATE
    FROM CUST_ORDER_LINE
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_ORDER ON CUST_ORDER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID = CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID
    WHERE 
      CUSTOMER_ORDER.ORDER_DATE BETWEEN CASE
                                          WHEN @dp = @d THEN ( dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) - 3)
                                          ELSE ( dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) - 1)
                                        END
                                AND CASE
                                      WHEN @dp = @d THEN ( dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()),0))
                                      ELSE ( dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), + 1))
                                    END

    ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ORDER.ORDER_DATE DESC
```